# jQuery get contents (length) of an integer array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an integer array which looks like this:

```
 var _SingleScannedItemIds = [];
```

At some point I push some items inside the array itself like following:

```
 _SingleScannedItemIds.push(checkbox_value);
```

Now my question here is:

- How do I know if the array contains anything inside of it?
- How do I remove integer numbers from it, based on which parameter?

Can someone help me out? I'm using jQuery...

Comment: Doesn't matter what the array contains, `array.length` will still return the number of indices it contains?

Comment: @adeneo hold on I will try length.. I think I've already tried but it gives me an error inside of console

Comment: 1. You can check with length, sample usage is if(_SingleScannedItemsIds.length > 0) 2. You should search indexof slice or splice

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ Okay got it , it works.. What about removing specific ID from array? How would I do that? =_

Answer (score 2):

**How do I know if the array contains anything inside of it?**

```
if(_SingleScannedItemIds.length == 0)
```

**How do I remove integer numbers from it, based on which parameter?**

```
_SingleScannedItemIds.splice(pos, 1)
```

What the above does is it removes 1 element from the position pos.

EDIT

```
delete _SingleScannedItemIds[pos]
```

Makes the _SingleScannedItemIds[pos] = undefined and then you can reassign it later with ex. _SingleScannedItemIds[0] = "apple". assuming pos = 0

Comment: Thanks Andrew! So basically the the POS value would the checkbox value that I have, and it would remove the wanted item from the array?

Comment: Splice will remove the first item, this is not removing the stored number.

Comment: @J.Meijer exactly, this is my concern =(

Comment: @User987 Misread question. You can use delete _SingleScannedItemIds[pos]

Comment: which makes it undefined

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Has nothing to do here.

Just use  array.length array.splice()

Comment: Bunny thanks a lot for the reply... What does the array.splice do here exactly? Array.splice(value)  ?

Answer (score 1):

Splice(index, numberOfElementsToRemove)

Comment: Bunny, index is the checkbox value in my case?? And number of elements to remove would be 1 always , right ?

Answer (score 1):

To get the length of an array:

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, 4];
console.log(array.length);
```

Removing items from an array is done by the key:

```js
function remove(array, element) {
    const index = array.indexOf(element);
    array.splice(index, 1);
}

var array = [0, 1, 2, 4];
    
remove(array, 1); //removes number 1

console.log(array);
```